# A call to PInvoke function 'RawPrinterHelper::OpenPrinter' has unbalanced the stack

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Why do I get this error at runtime:

> Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'BoxBox!BoxBox.RawPrinterHelper::OpenPrinter' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

This is the part of my class that shows the error:

```
<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinterW",
   SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode,
   ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Long) As Boolean
End Function
```

I see that there is a problem with .NET framework above 2.0 but i really need to use .NET 4.5.2

Comment: Have you tried one of these top two [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/OpenPrinter.html)? Don't use the last example as it is for .NET 2.0

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me in the past with VB.NET 4.5

```
Private Structure PRINTER_DEFAULTS
    Public pDatatype As IntPtr
    Public pDevMode As IntPtr
    Public DesiredAccess As Integer
End Structure


<DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint:="OpenPrinter", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal pPrinterName As String, <Out> ByRef phPrinter As IntPtr, ByRef pDefault As PRINTER_DEFAULTS) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint:="ClosePrinter", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function ClosePrinter(ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Const ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED As Integer = &H5
Private Const PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER As Integer = &H4 'Printing-specific access rights for printers to perform administrative tasks
Private Const PRINTER_ACCESS_USE As Integer = &H8 'Printing-specific access rights for printers to perform basic printing operations
Private Const PRINTER_ACCESS_MANAGE_LIMITED As Integer = &H40 'Printing-specific access rights for printers to perform printer data management operations
Private Const PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS As Integer = &HF000C 'Access rights for printers to perform all administrative tasks and basic printing operations except synchronization. Combines WO (Write Owner), WD (Write DACL), RC (Read Control), and DE (Delete) of ACCESS_MASK with printing-specific PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER and printing-specific PRINTER_ACCESS_USE.
Private Const PRINTER_READ As Integer = &H20008 'Access rights for printers combining RC (Read Control) of ACCESS_MASK with printing-specific PRINTER_ACCESS_USE.
```